# Storing the customized django auth_user model

Tags: django, authentication

I am working on a website and for the login information, I am using a customized `MyUser` model that is a subclass of the original `User` model. Now, to create `MyUser` records, i use

```
x = MyUser.objects.create(
    username = #something,
    password = #something,
    ...
 )
 x.save()
```

etc. Now, the MyUser record is created. But when I go to my admin page, I see type of password as:

```
 Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.
```

And `authenticate(username,password)` returns None and it works properly only if i go to admin and change the password. What is the best solution to store the `MyUser` data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`set_password` functionality provided by django `User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password)

```
x = MyUser.objects.create(
    username = #something,
    ...
 )
x.set_password(#something)
x.save()
```

Now, `set_password` would apply the hashing algorithm, and store the encrypted password for you, where as what you are doing would just set the plain text password, which is the issue.